# Table name and not table being displayed R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to print a table in R shiny, however, it keeps printing the table name and not the table. The table name is saved as a reactive variable then put into render table but it just keeps printing the table name.

How can I solve this problem?

```
server=function(input, output){

cord <- reactive({matrix(c(input$long,input$lat),nrow=1,ncol=2)})

ans=reactive({distHaversine(c(b[1,2],b[1,3]),c(cord()[,1],cord()[,2]))})

for (i in 1:15){
  distance=reactive({distHaversine(c(b[i,2],b[i,3]),c(cord()[,1],cord()[,2]))})

test=reactive({
  if(distance() < ans())
  {
  ans()=distance()
  name=reactive({CO[i,1]})
  }
})
}


data=reactive({name()})
output$table<-renderTable({data()})
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any data or any idea really what you're trying to do its hard to help, that being said heres my attempt by speculating of what you want to do. I've tidied up a bit and added `req()`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(renderTable("table"))

server <- function(input, output, session){

  v <- reactiveValues()

  cord <- reactive({
    req(input$long)
    req(input$lat)
    mc <- matrix(c(input$long,input$lat),nrow=1,ncol=2)
    v$ans <- distHaversine(mc(b[1,2],b[1,3]),c(mc[,1],mc[,2]))
    mc
  })

  data <- reactive({

    for(i in 1:15){
      distance <- distHaversine(c(b[i,2],b[i,3]),c(cord()[,1],cord()[,2]))

      if(distance < v$ans){
        v$ans <- distance
        return(CO[i,1])
      }
    }
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```